# History of the Surname 'Salmon'

Tags: history

I was wondering if any one might know anything about the history, origin and or background of my family name, Salmon.  Any information would be gratefully received! 
Thank you

Comment: This question is impossible to answer because we don't know your family history, or indeed who you are. There can be any number of theories but we can't possibly know which one applies *in your particular case*.

Answer (score 1):

[Surname Database](http://www.surnamedb.com/surname/salmon) has a good entry on Salmon and its origins:

Extract:

> This intriguing and unusual name is of early medieval English origin, and derives from the Middle English and Old French given name "Salmon" or "Saumon", a contracted form of Salomon. The ultimate origin of the personal name is from the Hebrew male given name "Shelomo", a derivative of "shalom", peace. Salomon and its variant forms was a popular given name among Christians and Jews during the Middle Ages; it is recorded as "Salomon" in the Domesday Book of 1086, and one "Salamon clericus" is recorded in Suffolk in 1121.

Comment: Are you tall?                                                                                                                         "Jack of legs, a tall long legged man; also a giant, said to
be buried in Weston Church, near Baldock, in Hertford-
shire, where there are two stones fourteen feet distant,
said to be the head and feet stones of his grave. This
giant, fays Salmon, as fame goes, lived in a wood here,
and was a great robber, but a generous one, for be plun-
dered" -Blackguardiana: or, A dictionary of rogues.Caulfield, James, 1764-1826.

Comment: I quite enjoy the fact that my paternal grandmother was a Salmon. But to spoil things for my punning generation, the family pronounced the "l", which gives credence to the Salomon derivation.